# printing R string in a specific format

Tags: r

I have a string that's something like this:

```
string_needed <- Choose 1: Option A, Option B, Option C; Drinks: Option E
```

How do i format the above string so that each time i call "string_needed", it prints:

```
CHOOSE 1:
Option A, Option B, Option C

DRINKS:
Option E
```

As you can see it does two things. When it detects a ":" it caps anything before it and goes to next line and when it detects ";" it goes to the next line as well as breaks in between.

Much help would be needed in this!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"How do i format the above string so that each time i call "string_needed", it prints: [...]"*.

You could define a custom print function that parses the string and formats the output according to your expected output.

```
string_needed <- "Choose 1: Option A, Option B, Option C; Drinks: Option E"

my_print <- function(ss) {
    lst <- sapply(strsplit(ss, "; "), strsplit, ": ")
    for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
        cat(paste(replace(lst[[i]], 1, toupper(lst[[i]][1])), collapse = "\n"))
        cat("\n\n")
    }
}

my_print(string_needed)
#CHOOSE 1
#Option A, Option B, Option C
#
#DRINKS
#Option E
```